# Delete first case

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, core-language

How to delete just first occurrence of given value from a list?
Without sorting etc.
Something like this:

```
DeleteFirstCase[{1/3, 1/2, 3/4, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, 1/2] -> {1/3, 3/4, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2}
```

Only

```
arr = {1/3, 1/2, 3/4, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2};
item = 1/2;
arr = Delete[arr, First@Position[arr, item]];
```

?

Comment: See the 3rd paradigm of the output of `?DeleteCases`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
arr = {1/3, 1/2, 3/4, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2}
item = 1/2
FixedPointList[DeleteCases[#, item, {1}, 1] &, arr] // Grid
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, `DeleteCases[arr, item, {1}, 1]`

Answer (score 4):

Using `DeleteElements`:

```
DeleteElements[{1/3, 1/2, 3/4, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, 1 -> {1/2}]

(*{1/3, 3/4, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2}*)
```

For 12.1 version, you can use `SubsetReplace`:

```
SubsetReplace[{1/3, 1/2, 3/4, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2}, {1/2} -> Nothing, 1]
 (*{1/3, 3/4, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2}*)
```

Your `DeleteFirstCase` using `PositionIndex` and `KeyTake`:

```
 DeleteFirstCase[l_List, item_] := 
 Module[{rules}, 
  rules = Flatten[
    Thread /@ (If[#[[2]] === item, 
         Rest[#[[1]]] -> #[[2]], #] & /@ (Reverse /@ 
         Normal@PositionIndex[l]))];
  (Join @@ Normal[KeyTake[rules, #] & /@ Range[Length[l]]])[[All, 2]]]
```

Test:

```
DeleteFirstCase[arr, item]
(*{1/3, 3/4, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2}*)
```

Using `DeteleFirstCase` with `FixedPointList`:

```
FixedPointList[DeleteFirstCase[#, item] &, arr] // Grid
```

[image]

Comment: Well, it's just from 13.1 
Thank you, but  i need something with backward compatibility for version 12 and under, for some reasons

Answer (score 2):

```
lst//Drop[#,FirstPosition[#,1/2]]&
```

$$\left\{\frac{1}{3},\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right\}$$